# Using SSAS to Cluster a Simple Dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssas, data-mining

I'm going through [this](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2993/data-mining-clustering-example-in-sql-server-analysis-services-ssas/) tutorial. Everything is understandable to me except for this part:

[image]

**What is the purpose / meaning of the lines which connect the clusters?**

As the tutorial states, the clusters will actually look like this if you plot them:

[image]

But I am not understanding the purpose of the lines connecting the clusters. There's nothing in the code, that's implicit about the clusters being connected in some way:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblClusterExample](
    pkClusterExample int identity (1,1) primary key,
 [AttributeX] [decimal](18, 4) NOT NULL,
 [AttributeY] [decimal](18, 4) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
insert into dbo.tblClusterExample values (rand()/10 +0.8, rand()/10 +0.8)
insert into dbo.tblClusterExample values (rand()/10 +0.2, rand()/10 +0.8)
insert into dbo.tblClusterExample values (rand()/10 +0.2, rand()/10 +0.2)
insert into dbo.tblClusterExample values (rand()/10 +0.8, rand()/10 +0.2)
go 10000
select top 10 * from dbo.tblClusterExample
```

**Where is the gap in my understanding?**

Comment: There's a severe lack of good documentation on the statistical tools that Microsoft uses in their products and the meaning behind the data generated by these tools. Might I suggest a book or course on the underlying mathematical/statistical techniques used by the toolset?

Comment: please do suggest one

Comment: Coursera offers an introductory course in the various methods - https://www.coursera.org/course/datan

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps if you hover your mouse over the line it might give centroid distance( i am not sure).I have not used this software.Nonetheless lines are just for visual interpretation.Unless they give some distance measure, they are not useful in any way.